# Seleccionar una fila de mi dataframe y generar un pdf de esa fila en rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

tengo un dataframe en Rstudio, en donde quisiera generar un pdf así como tipo carné de una única fila (una sola fila)

```
        nombre     edad     ciudad    peso         correo
1      Santiago    22      Bogotá     77    santiago@correo.com
2      Valeria     25      Cali       69    valiera@correo.com
```

quisiera solo imprimir en mi pdf la fila 1, es decir (datos de Santiago)

mi dataframe lo tengo almacenado en la variable **Datos**

Comment: Por ahora creé una nueva columna donde me enumera mis datos, y la estoy llamando por fila mediante este comando primerpaciente = Datos[peques$enum_neonatos == 1,]

enum_neonatos fue una nueva columna (vuelvo y menciono), pero ahora quisiera crear mi pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exportar a pdf en R de la manera deseada, son necesarios varios pasos.

En primer lugar, instalamos los paquetes siguientes:

```r
install.packages("knitr")
install.packages("rmarkdown")
install.packages("tinytex")
```

Una vez instalados los paquetes, los cargamos a nuestro entorno de trabajo.

```r
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
library(tinytex)
```

Ejecutamos los siguiente para instalar una distribución de Latex, necesaria para generar archivos PDF con R usando este método:

```r
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

En segundo lugar, creamos un archivo `.Rmd` que será nuestra plantilla para generar los archivos PDF.

Para este ejemplo, nombramos al archivo `reporteejemplo.Rmd` y está situado en nuestra carpeta de trabajo.

Su contenido será siguiente:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
params:
  persona: params$persona
---
  
```{r, echo=FALSE, comment=NA}
params$persona
```
````

Finalmente, ejecutamos el siguiente código, que generará un data frame llamado `datos`. Después, dentro de un bucle `for`, generará un archivo pdf por cada renglón en el data frame.

```r
datos <- "'nombre'     'edad'     'ciudad'    'peso'         'correo'
'Santiago'    22      'Bogotá'     77    'santiago@correo.com'
'Valeria'     25      'Cali'       69    'valiera@correo.com'"

df <- read.table(text = datos, header = TRUE)


for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  nombre_archivo <- paste0("persona_", i, ".pdf")
  
  render(input = "reporteejemplo.Rmd", 
         params = list(persona = df[i, ]), 
         output_file = nombre_archivo)
}
```

El resultado serán dos archivos pdf, `persona_1.pdf` y `persona_2.pdf`, con los datos del primer y segundo renglón del data frame, respectivamente.

Es posible modificar el archivo `reporteejemplo.Rmd` para dar formato a la salida.

Comment: no entiendo muy bien la parte que está después de **tinytex::install_tinytex()**, donde dice que nombras al archivo, no se muy bien donde va esa parte de codigo que pones ahí

Comment: ¡Hola! Se refiere a crear un archivo completamente nuevo con el nombre mencionado. No necesariamente se tiene que hacer con R, se puede crear con cualquier método, siempre que tenga la extensión y contenido mostrado para este ejemplo.